# java.util.Date and getYear()

Tags: java, date

I am having the following problem in Java (I see some people are having
a similar problem in JavaScript but I'm using Java)

```
System.out.println(new Date().getYear());
System.out.println(new GregorianCalendar().getTime().getYear());
System.out.println(this.sale.getSaleDate().getYear());
System.out.println(this.sale.getSaleDate().getMonth());
System.out.println(this.sale.getSaleDate().getDate());
```

returns

```
I/System.out( 4274): 112
I/System.out( 4274): 112
I/System.out( 4274): 112
I/System.out( 4274): 1
I/System.out( 4274): 11
```

I don't understand the 112 bit which I thought would have been 2012.
What's going on? Is the
`java.util.Date` class unusable? I am storing this as a field in several
of my classes to store a date and time. What should I do?

Comment: dear OP, it is because in the class it subtracts 1900 from it so to get the year pls add 1900 to it ..source-java file(`@Deprecated
    public int getYear() {
        return normalize().getYear() - 1900;
    }`)

Comment: While the `getYear` method was deprecated 14 years before this question was asked, the entire `Date` class has later been replaced with [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Use for example a `LocalDate` instead of `Date`. And be completely free from such surprises.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to javadocs:

```
@Deprecated
public int getYear()
```

**Deprecated**. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900`.

Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

**Returns:**
the year represented by this date, minus 1900.

**See Also:**
[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

So 112 is the correct output. I would follow the advice in the Javadoc or use JodaTime instead.

Comment: the correct implementation of a totally bizaare spec!

Comment: Is this the Y2K bug?

Comment: @jumpnett - no, this is not a bug at all, it works exactly as it's supposed to. It returns the current year offset by 1900. Why someone in Sun thought that was a good idea is a completely different question.

Comment: Must have been an intern though I'd love to hear what sun has to say about it

Answer (score 113):

In addition to all the comments, I thought I might add some code on how to use java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar and java.util.GregorianCalendar according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
//Initialize your Date however you like it.
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
//Add one to month {0 - 11}
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 43):

Use date format

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(datetime);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
year = df.format(date);
```

Answer (score 27):

Don't use `Date`, use `Calendar`:

```
// Beware: months are zero-based and no out of range errors are reported
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 9, 5);
int year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);  // 2012
int month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);  // 9 - October!!!
int day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  // 5
```

It supports time as well:

```
Calendar dateTime = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17);
int hour = dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  // 15
int minute = dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);  // 16
int second = dateTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);  // 17
```

Comment: Thanks for the 'BEWARE' statement. Would have been tricky to pick up and could have potentially ended up in production.

Answer (score 14):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()       // Capture the date-only value current in the JVM’s current default time zone.
         .getYear()   // Extract the year number from that date.
```

> 2018

## java.time

Both the `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes are legacy, now supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

If you want only the date without time-of-day, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). This class lacks time zone info but you can specify a time zone to determine the current date.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

You can get the various pieces of information with `getYear`, `getMonth`, and `getDayOfMonth`. You will actually get the year number with java.time!

```
int year = localDate.getYear();
```

> 2016

If you want a date-time instead of just a date, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 14):

The java documentation suggests to make use of Calendar class instead of this deprecated way
Here is the sample code to set up the calendar object

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
```

Here is the sample code to get the year, month, etc.

```
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Calendar also has support for many other useful information like, TIME, DAY_OF_MONTH, etc. Here the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) listing all of them
Please note that the month are 0 based. January is 0th month.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10):

Yup, this is in fact what's happening. See also the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29):

> ```
> Returns:
>    the year represented by this date, minus 1900.
> ```

The getYear method is deprecated for this reason. So, don't use it.

Note also that getMonth returns a number between 0 and 11. Therefore, `this.sale.getSaleDate().getMonth()` returns 1 for February, instead of 2. While `java.util.Calendar` doesn't add 1900 to all years, it does suffer from the off-by-one-month problem.

You're much better off using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 10):

Java 8 LocalDate class is another option to get the year from a java.util.Date,

```
int year = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date)).getYear();
```

Another option is,

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date));
```

Comment: Why would you mix the troublesome legacy class `SimpleDateFormat` with the modern *java.time* classes? Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the class that entirely replaces `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 7):

There are may ways of getting day, month and year in java.

You may use any-

```
    Date date1 = new Date();
    String mmddyyyy1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(date1);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 1: " + mmddyyyy1);



    Date date2 = new Date();
    Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar1.setTime(date2);
    int day1   = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // {0 - 11}
    int year1  = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String mmddyyyy2 = ((month1<10)?"0"+month1:month1) + "-" + ((day1<10)?"0"+day1:day1) + "-" + (year1);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 2: " + mmddyyyy2);



    LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.now();  
    DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");  
    String mmddyyyy3 = ldt1.format(format1);  
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 3: " + mmddyyyy3);  



    LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.now();
    int day2 = ldt2.getDayOfMonth();
    int mont2= ldt2.getMonthValue();
    int year2= ldt2.getYear();
    String mmddyyyy4 = ((mont2<10)?"0"+mont2:mont2) + "-" + ((day2<10)?"0"+day2:day2) + "-" + (year2);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 4: " + mmddyyyy4);



    LocalDateTime ldt3 = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 6, 11, 14, 30); // int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute
    DateTimeFormatter format2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");  
    String mmddyyyy5 = ldt3.format(format2);   
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 5: " + mmddyyyy5); 



    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(new Date());
    int day3  = calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // OR Calendar.DATE
    int month3= calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int year3 = calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String mmddyyyy6 = ((month3<10)?"0"+month3:month3) + "-" + ((day3<10)?"0"+day3:day3) + "-" + (year3);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 6: " + mmddyyyy6);



    Date date3 = new Date();
    LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date3)); // Accepts only yyyy-MM-dd
    int day4  = ld1.getDayOfMonth();
    int month4= ld1.getMonthValue();
    int year4 = ld1.getYear();
    String mmddyyyy7 = ((month4<10)?"0"+month4:month4) + "-" + ((day4<10)?"0"+day4:day4) + "-" + (year4);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 7: " + mmddyyyy7);



    Date date4 = new Date();
    int day5   = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date4)).getDayOfMonth();
    int month5 = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date4)).getMonthValue();
    int year5  = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date4)).getYear();
    String mmddyyyy8 = ((month5<10)?"0"+month5:month5) + "-" + ((day5<10)?"0"+day5:day5) + "-" + (year5);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 8: " + mmddyyyy8);



    Date date5 = new Date();
    int day6   = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(date5));
    int month6 = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(date5));
    int year6  = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date5));
    String mmddyyyy9 = ((month6<10)?"0"+month6:month6) + "-" + ((day6<10)?"0"+day6:day6) + "-" + (year6);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date 9: " + mmddyyyy9);
```

Comment: I'm getting Date() requires arguments

Comment: @john ktejik;  In java new Date() creates a date object which contains current date and time whereas new Date(long milliseconds) which you are asking for; creates a date object as per argument in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. 
Also in JavaScript you can use argumented Date() like- new Date(milliseconds), new Date(timestamp) or new Date(dateString) etc.

Answer (score 3):

## `Year.now()`

There's an easier way to use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#now--) library in Java 8+.  The expression:

```
java.time.Year.now().getValue()
```

returns the current year as a four-digit int, using your default time zone.  There are lots of options for different time [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)s, [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)s and [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html)s, but I think this is what you will want most of the time.  If you want the code to look cleaner (and don't need any other java.time.*.now() functions), put:

```
import static java.time.Year.now;
```

at the top of your file, and call:

```
now().getValue()
```

as needed.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is documented in the [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29) -class documentation:

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year
>   that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this
>   Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

It is also marked as deprecated. Use [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
        try{ 
int year = Integer.parseInt(new Date().toString().split("-")[0]); 
} 
catch(NumberFormatException e){
}
```

Much of Date is deprecated.

Comment: I suggest doing something in the exception. (For example code, just a comment "do something here" will do).  "Eating" an exception is bad practice, it makes debugging hard.

Comment: please add more details