# Counters in Loops in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Is there a way to do a loop in Thymeleaf without a list?

I'd like to essentially convert this snippet to Thymeleaf:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="year" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy" />
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="99">
    <form:option value="${year-i}" />
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

-- Update --

I've decided this is along the lines of how I want to do it, but I'm not sure about the springEL syntax:

```
<option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 100)}" th:value="#{ T(java.util.Date).getYear() - $i }">1</option>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In case you are still looking for the correct SpEL syntax, 
here's what worked for me:

```
<option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 100)}"
        th:value="${ (new org.joda.time.DateTime()).getYear() - i }"
        th:text="${ (new org.joda.time.DateTime()).getYear() - i }">1</option>
```

**Notice:**

- added `th:text` to set the option text.
- used Joda-Time instead as `java.util.Date` wouldn't give me the desired outcome

Read this discussion on [java.util.Date and getYear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243578/java-util-date-and-getyear)

Answer (score 23):

You can use the special thymleaf iteration variable inside the each block.
This special variable name is the name of your element variable concatenate with the keyword `'Stat'` (ex: `elt -> eltStat`)
This variable gives you many information related to the iteration.

You can also specify this variable name after your element variable. For example:

```html
<tr th:each="prod,iterStat : ${prods}" th:class="${iterStat.odd}? 'odd'">
    <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.inStock}? #{true} : #{false}">yes</td>
</tr>
```

More information in the official documentation below:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status

Comment: @PriiduNeemre "_This is much cleaner than the accepted answer_" . But the question clearly says that to keep the iteration counter without a List. In the above code `${prods}` is a list.