# java.sql.Date not printing correct date

Tags: java

The following code prints out "3920-06-02", but it's supposed to be "2020-05-02". What did I do wrong?

```
import java.sql.Date
// ...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date May0220 = new Date(2020,  5,  2);
    System.out.println(May0220.toString());
}
```

I want to use java.sql and not java.util.

Comment: Don't use that constructor. It's been deprecated for 15 years now.

Comment: @TheImpaler So what do I do instead?

Comment: You probably want a local date without time. If so use java.time.LocalDate. Is there any specific reason you want to use java.sql.Date?

Comment: use LocalDate like this `LocalDate May0220 = LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 2);`

Comment: @TheImpaler I want java.sql.Date because I want that specific format since it works with the SQL Date type. I'm changing every Date into LocalDate to see if it works.

Comment: You can also create java.sql.Date from LocalDate: `Date sqlDate = Date.valueOf(May0220)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29168494

Comment: TheImpaler, falknis - Thanks, it works!

Comment: *"What did I do wrong?"* You didn't **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of the [`Date` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date-int-int-int-).

Comment: `LocalDate` works very nicely with SQL date. [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2). You don’t want `java.sql.Date`. It’s poorly designed (you haven’t seen but a slight bit of its problems) and long outdated.

Comment: Closely related: [java.util.Date and getYear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243578/java-util-date-and-getyear)

Comment: If it's been deprecated since 15 years now, maybe it's time to just remove this technical debt already....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if java.sql.Date; uses the year from 1900, and uses array like indexing for the month, so it's off one less than what it should be.

This is what I did to get your desired result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Date May0220 = new Date(2020 - 1900, 5 - 1, 2);
    System.out.println(May0220+"");
}
```

A more general form would be

```
{
    int year = 2020;
    int month = 5;
    Date date = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, 2);
    System.out.println(date+"");
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing that but I thought there must be a more elegant way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRahmé Most JDBC drivers now support java.time.LocalDate using `setObject()` and `getObject()`. java.time.LocalDate is always local, while java.sql.Date is world time; they represent two different things. If your app runs in a different time zone than your database you'll see wrong conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this reference [How to Get Current Date and Time in Java](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-get-current-date) to get the output like you expected . I've Just modified the code in the example by removing the time part.

The librararies are **java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;** and **java.time.LocalDateTime**.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;  
public class PrintDateTime {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
 }  
}
```

Hope you find it useful !

Comment: Thanks for showing the modern solution! Still simpler would be `System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));`.